# Texture does not load with three.js

Tags: javascript, web-applications, three.js, vite

I use npx vite to run an application and want to render a card on scene. I assume that the camera and lights are okay, even the faces of the card are ok, because you can see the edeges of the card (depth) but the front and back textures are not loading. Also, the file system seems right to me, tried to use TextureLoader error detection and it did not detect any error and i still can not figure out why it is not rendering the texture.
[How files are placed and how i load the texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGFAh.jpg)

Code for main.js:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import{CARDS} from './cards';

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()

//Scene
const scene=new THREE.Scene()

//Create objects
/*const geometry=new THREE.SphereGeometry(5,64,64)
const material= new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color:"#00ff83",})
const mesh=new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material)*/

CARDS.forEach(function(card){
    scene.add(card)
    console.log(card)
})




//Light
const light=new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff,1,100)
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xA3A3A3, 1)
scene.add(ambientLight)
light.position.set(0,10,7)
scene.add(light)

//Camera
const camera=new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,800/600)
camera.position.set(0,10,6)
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,6,2))
scene.add(camera)

//Renderer
const canvas=document.querySelector('.webgl')
const renderer=new THREE.WebGL1Renderer({canvas})
renderer.setSize(800,600)
renderer.render(scene,camera)
```

Code for cards.js:

```
import{
    MeshBasicMaterial,
    BoxGeometry,
    Mesh,
    SRGBColorSpace,
    TextureLoader,
    Vector3
} from 'three';

const textureLoader=new TextureLoader();
const cardGeo = new BoxGeometry(0.4,0.7,0.03);

const citizen1Texture = textureLoader.load('textures/citizen1.png');
citizen1Texture.colorSpace=SRGBColorSpace;

const coverTexture = textureLoader.load('textures/cardback.png');
coverTexture.colorSpace=SRGBColorSpace;

const card1Mat=[
    new MeshBasicMaterial(),
    new MeshBasicMaterial(),
    new MeshBasicMaterial(),
    new MeshBasicMaterial(),
    new MeshBasicMaterial( {map:citizen1Texture} ),
    new MeshBasicMaterial( {map:coverTexture} )
];

const CARDS=[];

const cardsPositions=[
    new Vector3(0.5,7.005,3.21)
];

function configureCard(card,pos,name){
    card.name-name;
    card.castShadow=true;
    card.position.copy(pos[0]);
    CARDS.push(card);
}

const card1 = new Mesh(cardGeo,card1Mat);
configureCard(card1,cardsPositions,'card1');

export{CARDS}
```